# Trying to retrieve facebook user email using facebook connect for cordova 3.2

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm developing an android app wherein it requires to be logged into the app via facebook. I'm using facebook connect for cordova 3.2 and its working fine.But the problem is I'm not able to get the user's email address. I tried scope : email , permissions : 'email', but it simply does not work.I have installed facebook sdk for android the cordova 3.2 version and configured that with my project. I call the facebook login uri with a button click event.

```
var facebookConnect;
$("#facebookfbtn").unbind("click").click(function () {
  facebookConnect.login(loginCallback, true);
});
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, false);
function deviceready(){
  facebookConnect = window.plugins.facebookConnect;
}

loginCallback = function(result){
  alert(result);
  if(result == "OPENED")
  {
    facebookConnect.me(meCallback);
  }
}

logoutCallback = function(result){
  alert(result);
}

meCallback = function(result){
  alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  //var test = JSON.stringify(result);
  alert('Good to see you, ' + result.name  + '!' + '\n'+ 'Your Details :'+    '\n'+'Location:'+result.location+'\n'+'Email: '+result.email);
}

statusCallback = function(result){
  alert(result);
}
```